# Proper way to handle types for JS reduce with a list having union of types?

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash, reduce

Let's say we have a function segregateIds that separates a list of Ids into two parts by checking in a string-to-boolean map.

```
const segregateIds = (
  ids: string[] | number[],
  optionsById: Record<string, boolean>,
): { correctIds: string[] | number[]; incorrectIds: string[] | number[] } => {

  return ids.reduce<{ correctIds: string[] | number[]; incorrectIds: string[] | number[] }>(
    (accum: { correctIds: string[] | number[]; incorrectIds: string[] | number[] }, id: string | number) => {
      if (optionsById[id]) {
        accum.correctIds.push(id);
      } else {
        accum.incorrectIds.push(id);
      }

      return accum;
    },
    {
      correctIds: [],
      incorrectIds: [],
    }
  );
};
```

The problem here is that reduce is not accepting a list that has both string[] or number[]. Type coercion is a way to handle this. Is there something better?

Here is the [Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=21&ssc=3&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCmBzATkghleBJAJhGAvDABQBQMMAlngFxxTKViIDaAujAD4xgCuAtgCN4ydgBpyMEAAcolcBABCAT1x0ASvFDIcAHmiNmYmIJAgANvDRgAfBICUdAN4xtqYFFwQ6Bpqw7cfEIi7ADcVGBuWp609Ib+XDwCwqIcAL6ENjBOpJKoULzIYFR4AHSoOLzA8LouUR5ePgx+7IlBKWER9THecS0BScGpMGk2ZBQUxGjAwALOriDI7j1N8a2BySFs4UzdjX3M64Md6cbUq35tm8j2mdmSE1QAZiQycgoquCzUbLc5j49prN+KU9mVpLwIAALYjUeyhB4TDLwcwIe4AiZAgSlXaLZZeUoQ6GwnDwxEUNK5DH5QrFLH8BGPNISR7-AFg3ricldPHRfZcpmSMlpBFAA) to TS Playground

Expecting to resolve the TS error. Tried to type-coerce the accumulator, id but in vain. Tried using lodash reduce, partition but still error remains.

I can use `Array<string|number>` and pass to lodash partition but that will be tweaking the actual type as `Array<string|number>` is different from `string[] | number[]`.

Comment: The `string[] | number[]` type means either a list of strings or a list of numbers, but not mixed. The `(string | number)[]` or `Array<string | number>` types do have `string` and `number` mixed.

Comment: Yes, I do understand that `string[] | number[]` can't have mixed types in the array, hence I did not go with `Array<string | number>`. This function is intended to be a common function that can either receive a `string[]` or a `number[]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to [protob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75545568/5157454).

Since you marked the question with the lodash tag, you can use `_.partition()` instead of reduce:

```
const segregateIds = <T extends string | number>(
  ids: T[],
  optionsById: Record<string, boolean>,
): { correctIds: T[]; incorrectIds: T[] } => {
  const [correctIds, incorrectIds] = partition(ids, id => optionsById[String(id)]);

  return {
    correctIds,
    incorrectIds
  };
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use generic type `T` to accept arrays of strings or numbers:

```
const segregateIds = <T extends string | number>(
  ids: T[],
  optionsById: Record<string, boolean>,
): { correctIds: T[]; incorrectIds: T[] } => {

  return ids.reduce<{ correctIds: T[]; incorrectIds: T[] }>(
    (accum: { correctIds: T[]; incorrectIds: T[] }, id: T) => {
      if (optionsById[id.toString()]) {
        accum.correctIds.push(id);
      } else {
        accum.incorrectIds.push(id);
      }

      return accum;
    },
    {
      correctIds: [],
      incorrectIds: [],
    }
  );
```